# Adjusting column width in Table (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get the column width on mobile to become 50%, but everything I've tried hasn't worked. This is the css.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

#customTable tbody { float: left; }
#customTable thead { float: left; }
#customTable thead { min-width: 120px }
#customTable td { display: block }
#customTable th { display: block }
#customTable {table-layout: fixed;}
#customTable td {width: 50%;}
#customTable td {height: 20px; overflow: hidden;}
#customTable div {height: 20px;overflow: hidden;}
}
```

Here is the html

```
 <div class="table">
<table id="customTable" class="table" style="width: 100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><LABEL>Test 1</LABEL></td>
        <th><LABEL>Test 2</LABEL></td>
        <th><LABEL>Test 3</LABEL></td>
        <th><LABEL>Test 4</LABEL></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>                
        <td><LABEL>Test</LABEL></td>
        <td><LABEL>Test</LABEL></td>
        <td><LABEL>Test</LABEL></td>
        <td><LABEL>Test</LABEL></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you expect 4 columns at 50% each? Isn't that 200% ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want column width to adjust, using tables, you actually need to tell it NOT to behave as a table any more.

e.g. use `display:block` and `width:50%` on your `#customTable td` and work from there as though they are block elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the width of columns, you should adjust the width of the **th** in **thead**.

this works on me fine.